# Strange error bars problem

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to get error bars to show correctly on my plot using `pgfplots`. I am wanting explicit relative error bars in both directions for my y-data, and what I am getting is perplexing. The error bars extend down to the bottom of the graph instead of being symmetric around the data points of interest, and within the relative range I have specified. 
[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.125,0.5,0.169}

\newcommand{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{7pt}{9pt}\selectfont}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{Td.dat}
theta   exp          sim          relativeerror   errorbars
10      5439.5       3241.8       -40.4026        0.036212
20      12256.5      10518.1      -14.1832        0.023798
30      18469.5      19819.8      7.3109          0.021885
40      26900        28341.3      5.358122        0.021386
50      40902        44859.2      9.674814        0.021262
60      46348        51647.4      11.43391        0.02124
70      43877        47986.3      9.365563        0.021231
80      41886.5      48017.3      14.63673        0.021239
90      24937        32576.7      30.63588        0.021409
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={at={(0.5,1.05)},anchor=south}, legend columns=3,
    xmin = 0, xmax = 100,
    xtick={10,30,...,90},
    minor x tick num=1,  
        y axis style/.style={yticklabel style=#1, ylabel style=#1, y axis line style=#1, ytick style=#1}
}

\begin{axis}[width=3.25in,height=3.25in,
    axis y line*=left,
    y axis style=black,
    minor y tick num=3,
    ymin = 0, ymax = 60000,
    %ytick={0,10000,...,60000},
    xlabel={Valve Angle Opening, $\theta$ (deg.)},
    ylabel={Hydrodynamic Torque, $T_{d \theta}$ (lbf-in)},
    scaled ticks=false]

    \addplot[darkgreen,mark=square, line width=1.0, densely dashed, mark options=solid,mark size=2.5,
        error bars/.cd, error mark=-, x dir=none, y dir=both, y explicit relative]
                table[x=theta, y=exp, y error=errorbars] {Td.dat};
        \label{expplot}

%    \addplot[blue,mark=o,line width=1.0,mark options=solid,mark size=2.5] 
%        table[x=theta,y=sim] {Td.dat};
%        \label{simplot}
\end{axis}


%\begin{axis}[width=3.25in,height=3.25in,
%    axis y line*=right,
%    axis x line=none,
%    minor y tick num=1,
%    ymin=-50, ymax=50,
%    ytick={-50,-40,...,50},
%    ylabel=Relative Difference from Experiment (\%),
%    y axis style=red!75!black,
%    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=0,/tikz/.cd},]
%
%    \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=expplot}\addlegendentry{Experiment}
%    \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=simplot}\addlegendentry{Simulation}
%
%    \addplot[red,mark=x, line width=1.0, densely dashed, mark options=solid,mark size=2.5] 
%        table[x=theta,y=relativeerror] {Td.dat};
%        \addlegendentry{Relative Diff.}
%\end{axis}



\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Anyone have a clue what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Comment: You should use the `filecontents*` environment so that the `filecontents` header is not written to the file. But even with that, this does not compile for me.  Please ensure the the MWE posted compiles for you.

Comment: @PeterGrill: PGFPlots ignores the header that's written by the `filecontents` package, so there's no need to use the `*` version here.

Answer (score 6):

Indeed it seems that `y explicit relative` key is defined but not used anywhere else. I couldn't find the respective code (might be a mistake on my side) Until someone can explain it you can use your own expression

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[green!50!black,mark=square, line width=1.0, densely dashed, mark options=solid,mark size=2.5,
          error bars/.cd, error mark=-, y dir=both, y explicit] 
                    table[y error expr={\thisrow{y}*\thisrow{erry}}] {
x y erry
10 5439.5   0.36212
20 12256.5  0.23798
30 18469.5  0.21885
40 26900    0.21386
50 40902    0.21262
60 46348    0.2124
70 43877    0.21231
80 41886.5  0.21239
90 24937    0.21409
        };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I've removed one zero after the decimal point from the `erry` data to make it visible.

Answer (score 5):

This is due to a bug in PGFPlots. I've filed a [bug report and fix](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3589122&group_id=224188&atid=1060656). Until the fix is incorporated, you can go with Percusse's workaround (recommended), or include the corrected function in your preamble:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\makeatletter
\def\pgfplots@PREPARE@errorbar@processing@in@dir#1{%
    \if0\csname pgfplots@errorbars@#1direction\endcsname
        % no error bars. Ok. Do nothing here.
        \expandafter\let\csname pgfplots@PREPARE@errorbar@process@#1\endcsname=\relax
    \else
        %
        % Prepare a macro which invokes
        % \pgfplots@streamerrorbarcoords.
        %
        % This involves to assign point coordinates in the correct
        % ordering; prepare that:
        \if x#1%
            \ifpgfplots@curplot@threedim
                \t@pgfplots@toka={%
                        {(\pgfplots@current@point@x,\pgfplots@current@point@y,\pgfplots@current@point@z)}%
                        {(\pgfplots@error@coord,\pgfplots@current@point@y,\pgfplots@current@point@z)}
                }%
            \else
                \t@pgfplots@toka={%
                        {(\pgfplots@current@point@x,\pgfplots@current@point@y)}%
                        {(\pgfplots@error@coord,\pgfplots@current@point@y)}
                }%
            \fi
        \else
            \if y#1%
                \ifpgfplots@curplot@threedim
                    \t@pgfplots@toka={%
                            {(\pgfplots@current@point@x,\pgfplots@current@point@y,\pgfplots@current@point@z)}%
                            {(\pgfplots@current@point@x,\pgfplots@error@coord,\pgfplots@current@point@z)}
                    }%
                \else
                    \t@pgfplots@toka={%
                            {(\pgfplots@current@point@x,\pgfplots@current@point@y)}%
                            {(\pgfplots@current@point@x,\pgfplots@error@coord)}
                    }%
                \fi
            \else
                \t@pgfplots@toka={%
                        {(\pgfplots@current@point@x,\pgfplots@current@point@y,\pgfplots@current@point@z)}%
                        {(\pgfplots@current@point@x,\pgfplots@current@point@y,\pgfplots@error@coord)}
                }%
            \fi
        \fi
        \begingroup
        % now, assemble the macro which will invoke
        % \pgfplots@streamerrorbarcoords:
        \let\E=\noexpand
        \expandafter\xdef\csname pgfplots@PREPARE@errorbar@stream@it@#1\endcsname{%
            \E\ifx\E\pgfplots@error@coord\E\pgfutil@empty
            \E\else
                \E\let\E\pgfplots@current@point@@old\expandafter\E\csname pgfplots@current@point@#1\endcsname
                \E\let\expandafter\E\csname pgfplots@current@point@#1\endcsname=\E\pgfplots@error@coord
                \E\pgfplotsaxisupdatelimitsforcoordinate\E\pgfplots@current@point@x\E\pgfplots@current@point@y\E\pgfplots@current@point@z
                \E\let\expandafter\E\csname pgfplots@current@point@#1\endcsname=\E\pgfplots@current@point@@old
                \E\edef\E\pgfplots@loc@TMPa{\the\t@pgfplots@toka}%
                \E\expandafter\E\pgfplots@streamerrorbarcoords\E\pgfplots@loc@TMPa
            \E\fi
        }%
        \endgroup
        %
        % The routine which is invoked for every reported input
        % coordinate is \pgfplots@process@errorbar@for.
        %
        % This here prepares its helper macros for direction '#1':
        \pgfplots@if{pgfplots@#1islinear}{%
            \ifcase\csname pgfplots@errorbars@#1mode\endcsname\relax
                % fixed absolute error.
                \pgfplotscoordmath{#1}{parsenumber}{\csname pgfplots@errorbars@#1fixed\endcsname}%
                \expandafter\let\csname pgfplots@error@coord@#1\endcsname=\pgfmathresult
                \expandafter\def\csname pgfplots@PREPARE@errorbar@process@#1@\endcsname##1{%
                    \if +##1%
                        \def\pgfplots@loc@TMPb{add}%
                    \else
                        \def\pgfplots@loc@TMPb{subtract}%
                    \fi
                    \pgfplotscoordmath{#1}{op}{\pgfplots@loc@TMPb}{%
                        {\csname pgfplots@current@point@#1\endcsname}%
                        {\csname pgfplots@error@coord@#1\endcsname}%
                    }%
                    \let\pgfplots@error@coord=\pgfmathresult
                    \csname pgfplots@PREPARE@errorbar@stream@it@#1\endcsname
                }%
            \or% fixed relative error:
                \pgfplotscoordmath{#1}{parsenumber}{\csname pgfplots@errorbars@#1rel\endcsname}%
                \let\pgfplots@loc@TMPb=\pgfmathresult
                %
                % +1:
                \pgfplotscoordmath{#1}{parsenumber}{1}%
                \let\pgfplots@loc@TMPa=\pgfmathresult
                %
                % Prepare '1 + err':
                \pgfplotscoordmath{#1}{op}{add}{%
                    {\pgfplots@loc@TMPa}%
                    {\pgfplots@loc@TMPb}%
                }%
                \expandafter\let\csname pgfplots@error@coord@#1@+\endcsname=\pgfmathresult
                %
                % Prepare '1 - err':
                \pgfplotscoordmath{#1}{op}{subtract}{%
                    {\pgfplots@loc@TMPa}%
                    {\pgfplots@loc@TMPb}%
                }%
                \expandafter\let\csname pgfplots@error@coord@#1@-\endcsname=\pgfmathresult
                %
                \expandafter\def\csname pgfplots@PREPARE@errorbar@process@#1@\endcsname##1{%
                    \pgfplotscoordmath{#1}{op}{multiply}{%
                        {\csname pgfplots@current@point@#1\endcsname}
                        {\csname pgfplots@error@coord@#1@##1\endcsname}%
                    }%
                    \let\pgfplots@error@coord=\pgfmathresult
                    \csname pgfplots@PREPARE@errorbar@stream@it@#1\endcsname
                }%
            \or% explicit absolute:
                \expandafter\def\csname pgfplots@PREPARE@errorbar@process@#1@\endcsname##1{%
                    \edef\pgfplots@error@coord{\csname pgfplots@current@point@#1@error\endcsname}%
                    \ifx\pgfplots@error@coord\pgfutil@empty
                    \else
                        \pgfplotscoordmath{#1}{parsenumber}{\pgfplots@error@coord}%
                        \pgfplotscoordmath{#1}{if is bounded}{\pgfmathresult}{%
                            \let\pgfplots@error@coord=\pgfmathresult
                            % remember result here - will be used in case
                            % of '+' AND '-' error bars:
                            \expandafter\let\csname pgfplots@current@point@#1@error\endcsname=\pgfmathresult
                            \if +##1%
                                \def\pgfplots@loc@TMPb{add}%
                            \else
                                \def\pgfplots@loc@TMPb{subtract}%
                            \fi
                            \pgfplotscoordmath{#1}{op}{\pgfplots@loc@TMPb}{%
                                {\csname pgfplots@current@point@#1\endcsname}%
                                {\pgfplots@error@coord}%
                            }%
                            \let\pgfplots@error@coord=\pgfmathresult
                            \csname pgfplots@PREPARE@errorbar@stream@it@#1\endcsname
                        }{%
                            % input is unbounded. Skip it.
                        }%
                    \fi
                }%
            \or% explicit relative:
                \expandafter\def\csname pgfplots@PREPARE@errorbar@process@#1@\endcsname##1{%
                    \edef\pgfplots@error@coord{\csname pgfplots@current@point@#1@error\endcsname}%
                    \ifx\pgfplots@error@coord\pgfutil@empty
                    \else
                        \pgfplotscoordmath{#1}{parsenumber}{\pgfplots@error@coord}%
                        \pgfplotscoordmath{#1}{if is bounded}{\pgfmathresult}{%
                            \let\pgfplots@error@coord=\pgfmathresult
                            % compute ' 1 + value' or '1-value':
                            \pgfplotscoordmath{#1}{one}%
                            \if +##1%
                                \def\pgfplots@loc@TMPb{add}%
                            \else
                                \def\pgfplots@loc@TMPb{subtract}%
                            \fi
                            \pgfplotscoordmath{#1}{op}{\pgfplots@loc@TMPb}{%
                                {\pgfmathresult}%
                                {\pgfplots@error@coord}%
                            }%
                            \let\pgfplots@error@coord=\pgfmathresult
                            \pgfplotscoordmath{#1}{op}{multiply}{%
                                {\csname pgfplots@current@point@#1\endcsname}
                                {\pgfplots@error@coord}%
                            }%
                            \let\pgfplots@error@coord=\pgfmathresult
                            \csname pgfplots@PREPARE@errorbar@stream@it@#1\endcsname
                        }{%
                            % input is unbounded. Skip it.
                        }%
                    \fi
                }%
            \fi
        }{%
            % LOGARITHMIC scaling. All errors are interpreted as 
            %   log(x +- e_x)
            % or
            %   log( x*(1+-e_x) )
            %
            % That means any input argument is
            % given in log base e and in fixed point.
            % Furthermore, we expect the '@unfiltered' keys to be
            % present (I don't want to apply 'exp' again!).
            %
            \ifcase\csname pgfplots@errorbars@#1mode\endcsname
                % fixed absolute, log( x +- e_x )
                %
                \pgfplotscoordmath{default}{parsenumber}{\csname pgfplots@errorbars@#1fixed\endcsname}%
                \expandafter\let\csname pgfplots@error@coord@#1\endcsname=\pgfmathresult
                \expandafter\def\csname pgfplots@PREPARE@errorbar@process@#1@\endcsname##1{%
                    \pgfplotscoordmath{default}{parsenumber}{\csname pgfplots@current@point@#1@unfiltered\endcsname}%
                    \let\pgfplots@loc@TMPa=\pgfmathresult
                    \if +##1%
                        \def\pgfplots@loc@op{add}%
                    \else
                        \def\pgfplots@loc@op{subtract}%
                    \fi
                    \pgfplotscoordmath{default}{op}{\pgfplots@loc@op}{%
                        {\pgfplots@loc@TMPa}%
                        {\csname pgfplots@error@coord@#1\endcsname}%
                    }%
                    \pgfplotscoordmath{default}{tostring}{\pgfmathresult}%
                    \pgfplotscoordmath{#1}{log}{\pgfmathresult}%
                    \let\pgfplots@error@coord=\pgfmathresult
                    \csname pgfplots@PREPARE@errorbar@stream@it@#1\endcsname
                }%
            \or% fixed relative, log( x ( 1+-e_x ) ) = log(x) + log(1+-e_x)
                \pgfplotscoordmath{default}{parsenumber}{\csname pgfplots@errorbars@#1rel\endcsname}%
                \let\pgfplots@loc@TMPb=\pgfmathresult
                %
                % +1:
                \pgfplotscoordmath{default}{one}%
                \let\pgfplots@loc@TMPa=\pgfmathresult
                %
                % Prepare '1 + err':
                \pgfplotscoordmath{default}{op}{add}{{\pgfplots@loc@TMPa}{\pgfplots@loc@TMPb}}%
                \pgfplotscoordmath{default}{tostring}{\pgfmathresult}%
                \pgfplotscoordmath{#1}{log}{\pgfmathresult}%
                \pgfplotscoordmath{#1}{if is bounded}{\pgfmathresult}{%
                }{%
                    % 1 + err <= 0  and log(1+err) is undefined:
                    \pgfplotscoordmath{default}{tostring}{\pgfplots@loc@TMPb}%
                    \pgfplots@error{Sorry, log(1 + \pgfmathresult) is undefined. Please provide a different argument for '/pgfplots/error bar/#1 fixed relative'.}%
                    \let\pgfmathresult=\pgfutil@empty
                }%
                \expandafter\let\csname pgfplots@error@coord@#1@+\endcsname=\pgfmathresult
                %
                % Prepare '1 - err':
                \pgfplotscoordmath{default}{op}{subtract}{{\pgfplots@loc@TMPa}{\pgfplots@loc@TMPb}}%
                \pgfplotscoordmath{default}{tostring}{\pgfmathresult}%
                \pgfplotscoordmath{#1}{log}{\pgfmathresult}%
                \pgfplotscoordmath{#1}{if is bounded}{\pgfmathresult}{%
                }{%
                    % 1 - err <= 0  and log(1+err) is undefined:
                    \pgfplotscoordmath{default}{tostring}{\pgfplots@loc@TMPb}%
                    \pgfplots@error{Sorry, log(1 - \pgfmathresult) (\pgfplots@loc@TMPa - \pgfplots@loc@TMPb) is undefined. Please provide a different argument for '/pgfplots/error bar/#1 fixed relative'.}%
                    \let\pgfmathresult=\pgfutil@empty
                }%
                \expandafter\let\csname pgfplots@error@coord@#1@-\endcsname=\pgfmathresult
                %
                \expandafter\def\csname pgfplots@PREPARE@errorbar@process@#1@\endcsname##1{%
                    \expandafter\ifx\csname pgfplots@current@point@#1@##1\endcsname\pgfutil@empty
                    \else
                        \pgfmath@basic@add@
                            {\csname pgfplots@current@point@#1\endcsname}
                            {\csname pgfplots@error@coord@#1@##1\endcsname}%
                        \let\pgfplots@error@coord=\pgfmathresult
                        \csname pgfplots@PREPARE@errorbar@stream@it@#1\endcsname
                    \fi
                }%
            \or% explicit absolute
                % log( x +- e_x )
                \expandafter\def\csname pgfplots@PREPARE@errorbar@process@#1@\endcsname##1{%
                    \edef\pgfplots@error@coord{\csname pgfplots@current@point@#1@error\endcsname}%
                    \ifx\pgfplots@error@coord\pgfutil@empty
                    \else
                        \pgfplotscoordmath{default}{parsenumber}{\pgfplots@error@coord}%
                        \pgfplotscoordmath{default}{if is bounded}{\pgfmathresult}{%
                            \let\pgfplots@error@coord=\pgfmathresult
                            % remember result here - will be used in case
                            % of '+' AND '-' error bars:
                            \expandafter\let\csname pgfplots@current@point@#1@error\endcsname=\pgfmathresult
                            \pgfplotscoordmath{default}{parsenumber}{\csname pgfplots@current@point@#1@unfiltered\endcsname}%
                            \let\pgfplots@loc@TMPa=\pgfmathresult
                            \if +##1%
                                \def\pgfplots@loc@op{add}%
                            \else
                                \def\pgfplots@loc@op{subtract}%
                            \fi
                            \pgfplotscoordmath{default}{op}{\pgfplots@loc@op}{%
                                {\pgfplots@loc@TMPa}%
                                {\pgfplots@error@coord}%
                            }%
                            \pgfplotscoordmath{default}{tostring}{\pgfmathresult}%
                            \pgfplotscoordmath{#1}{log}{\pgfmathresult}%
                            \let\pgfplots@error@coord=\pgfmathresult
                            \csname pgfplots@PREPARE@errorbar@stream@it@#1\endcsname
                        }{%
                            % input is unbounded. Skip it.
                        }%
                    \fi
                }%
                %
            \or% explicit relative:
                % log( x ( 1+-e_x ) ) = log(x) + log(1+-e_x)
                \expandafter\def\csname pgfplots@PREPARE@errorbar@process@#1@\endcsname##1{%
                    \edef\pgfplots@error@coord{\csname pgfplots@current@point@#1@error\endcsname}%
                    \ifx\pgfplots@error@coord\pgfutil@empty
                    \else
                        \pgfplotscoordmath{default}{parsenumber}{\pgfplots@error@coord}%
                        \pgfplotscoordmath{default}{if is bounded}{\pgfmathresult}{%
                            \let\pgfplots@error@coord=\pgfmathresult
                            % remember result here - will be used in case
                            % of '+' AND '-' error bars:
                            \expandafter\let\csname pgfplots@current@point@#1@error\endcsname=\pgfmathresult
                            %
                            \pgfplotscoordmath{default}{one}%
                            \let\pgfplots@loc@TMPa=\pgfmathresult
                            \if +##1%
                                \def\pgfplots@loc@op{add}%
                            \else
                                \def\pgfplots@loc@op{subtract}%
                            \fi
                            \pgfplotscoordmath{default}{op}{\pgfplots@loc@op}{%
                                {\pgfplots@loc@TMPa}%
                                {\pgfplots@error@coord}%
                            }%
                            \pgfplotscoordmath{default}{tostring}{\pgfmathresult}%
                            \pgfplotscoordmath{#1}{log}{\pgfmathresult}%
                            \let\pgfplots@error@coord=\pgfmathresult
                            \pgfplotscoordmath{#1}{if is bounded}{\pgfmathresult}{%
                                \pgfplotscoordmath{#1}{op}{add}{%
                                    {\csname pgfplots@current@point@#1\endcsname}
                                    {\pgfplots@error@coord}%
                                }%
                                \let\pgfplots@error@coord=\pgfmathresult
                                \csname pgfplots@PREPARE@errorbar@stream@it@#1\endcsname
                            }{%
                                % -> log( <= 0 ) -> do nothing.
                            }%
                        }{%
                            % input is unbounded - do nothing.
                        }%
                    \fi
                }%
                %
            \fi
        }%
        \ifcase\csname pgfplots@errorbars@#1direction\endcsname
            % none
        \or
            % plus
            \expandafter\edef\csname pgfplots@PREPARE@errorbar@process@#1\endcsname{%
                \expandafter\noexpand\csname pgfplots@PREPARE@errorbar@process@#1@\endcsname+%
            }%
        \or
            % minus
            \expandafter\edef\csname pgfplots@PREPARE@errorbar@process@#1\endcsname{%
                \expandafter\noexpand\csname pgfplots@PREPARE@errorbar@process@#1@\endcsname-%
            }%
        \or
            % both
            \expandafter\edef\csname pgfplots@PREPARE@errorbar@process@#1\endcsname{%
                \expandafter\noexpand\csname pgfplots@PREPARE@errorbar@process@#1@\endcsname+%
                \expandafter\noexpand\csname pgfplots@PREPARE@errorbar@process@#1@\endcsname-%
            }%
        \fi
    \fi
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{Td.dat}
theta   exp          sim          relativeerror   errorbars
10      5439.5       3241.8       -40.4026        0.036212
20      12256.5      10518.1      -14.1832        0.023798
30      18469.5      19819.8      7.3109          0.021885
40      26900        28341.3      5.358122        0.021386
50      40902        44859.2      9.674814        0.021262
60      46348        51647.4      11.43391        0.02124
70      43877        47986.3      9.365563        0.021231
80      41886.5      48017.3      14.63673        0.021239
90      24937        32576.7      30.63588        0.021409
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={at={(0.5,1.05)},anchor=south}, legend columns=3,
    xmin = 0, xmax = 100,
    xtick={10,30,...,90},
    minor x tick num=1,  
        y axis style/.style={yticklabel style=#1, ylabel style=#1, y axis line style=#1, ytick style=#1}
}

\begin{axis}[width=3.25in,height=3.25in,
    axis y line*=left,
    y axis style=black,
    minor y tick num=3,
    ymin = 0, ymax = 60000,
    scaled ticks=false]

    \addplot[error bars/.cd, error mark=-, x dir=none, y dir=both, y explicit relative]
                table[x=theta, y=exp, y error=errorbars] {Td.dat};
        \label{expplot}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```